# Does collecting all the flowers/coins/stars mean anything?

Tags: yoshis-new-island

At the end of the level, the game counts the flowers and coins and stars you have (out of 5, 20, and 30 respectively) and counts each as a "mission" in the level. I have yet to manage to complete all three missions in one level - what happens if I do?

Comment: If I recall correctly, in the SNES version, getting all of them on every level in an entire world unlocked a bunch of bonus stuff.  I don't know about the new game, but I assume it's probably something similar and worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

When you finish a level after collecting 30 stars, 20 red coins or 5 flowers, you get that item's tick mark. When you collect all three tick marks for a level, That level's icon will have a little flag and excited lines. Unlike the original Yoshi's Island, you do not need to complete all three challenges in the same attempt; you can, for example, collect the coins and flowers one time then come back and just get the stars while ignoring the rest.

When all 8 levels in a world have a flag, you will unlock that world's special level, with its own stars, coins and flowers to collect

Comment: At the moment, I don't know if there is a reward for flagging all the special levels. If someone knows, please add that information